# What is the release pace for English dub of Black Clover?

Tags: black-clover

I've looked up on the internet for an air date of the dubbed version for episode 45-48 of *Black Clover*, but didn't see any.

When will they come, or are there no more coming out in the dub? Or, is there a known release pace for the English dub?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Black_Clover_episodes), the English dub of episode 37 will air on September 9.
Assuming that it continues with one new episode per week, episode 45 will air on November 4.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really think to look at wikipedia for some reason.